# How can I hide the Permalink/Shortlink for certain user logged in Users of a certain level?

Tags: shortcode, permalinks

I would like to keep logged in Users who can write and edit their own posts from seeing the Permalink/Shortcode for the post (located under the Title field). I've been able to cut out other features but can't figure this one out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There're two functions: [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) && [`current_user_can('capability_type')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) that will help you to acchieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. But what you told me I already understand. I should have mentioned that I know how to write the function. I don't know, however, what the tag or name is for the Permalink/Shortcode section. Any idea what that may be?

Comment: fyi- you should post responses to answers as comments, that way the person who answered will get your message in their inbox. if you have additional details relating to your question you can edit your original question. answers should be reserved for posts that answer the question.

Comment: OK. Umm...I only see "link" and "edit". Am I missing something? I can, obviously, comment on this, my own answer. ??

Comment: hmm, maybe stackexchange doesn't let you comment on other answers if you're below a certain rep? that's... odd. the way this place works can be confusing at times.